# How to insert data with blank record in the database using shell script?

Tags: mysql, database, shell, unix

```
116,1,29084918,,,6
```

I have the records above (comma delimited). I need to load it to database using shell script (.ctl). Is it possible to load the blank record (4th and 5th field above) in the database in the same field? the output must be like

```
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5  Field6
116     1     29084918                6
```

Comment: If your records were comma-delimited, then `Field1`'s value would be '116 1'.  But you split those into 2 fields.  And then you somehow collapsed 3 empty fields into 2 fields - how?  Based on what?  What do you do when there are 3 values there?  So you need to explain your input file format better.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/366147/insert-one-data-to-mysql-table-without-login

Comment: Sorry for the typo error. I just want to know if I can load the records above with the expected output I've provided.

Comment: It also depends on your table. Do all the fields accept `null` values?